# Every regular Hausdorff H-closed space is compact.

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

Where could I find a formal proof of the following fact: "Every regular Hausdorff H-closed space is compact.". I have been looking in some books (Munkres for example) but I have not been able to find a complete proof yet. With COVID restrictions I can no longer just peek at library books, I have to ask for them and wait some days for them to be given to me, so I need to know in advance which book has what I need.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would try with the reference given in the wikipedia page about H-closed spaces https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-closed_space

Comment: The result is shown in Porter and Woods’ book *extensions and absolutes of Hausdorff spaces*. See [here](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781461283164)

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you very much, that was really useful.

Comment: Do you already know the characterisation of $H$-closed spaces that I used in my answer?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I'm working with another definition (every continuous embedding in a Hausdorff space has closed image) but I think I can work out the equivalence.

Comment: The equivalence is not entirely trivial (but also in the book I mentioned).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I am stumbling in a much more trivial question, right now, how can I be sure any embedding exists at all?. I have studied embeddings but I know almost nothing about when embedding exists between two spaces.

Comment: You can see my old proof on bbqa [here](http://at.yorku.ca/b/ask-a-topologist/2002/0386.htm). You can define your own embedding using an extension by 1 point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123286/discussion-between-henno-brandsma-and-zanzag).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Hausdorff space $X$ is $H$-closed iff for every open cover $\mathcal{U}$, there are finitely many $U_1,\ldots U_n \in \mathcal{U}$ such that $\bigcup_{i=1}^n \overline{U_i} = X$.

Now if $X$ is regular and $H$-closed Hausdorff space, let $\mathcal{O}$ be an open cover for $X$. Define $$\mathcal{U}=\{U \subseteq X \mid U \text{ open and }  \exists O \in \mathcal{O}: \overline{U} \subseteq O\}$$

and because $X$ is regular and $\mathcal{O}$ is an open cover, $\mathcal{U}$ is an open cover of $X$ as well (show this!).

Now apply the above characterisation of $H$-closed sets to find $U_1, \ldots, U_n \in \mathcal{U}$ such that $\bigcup_{i=1}^n \overline{U_i} = X$. For each $U_i \in \mathcal{U}$ we can find by definition some $O_i \in \mathcal{O}$ such that $\overline{U_i} \subseteq O_i$ and it follows that $\bigcup_{i=1}^n O_i = X$, and we have found a finite subcover for $\mathcal{O}$, so $X$ is compact.